# Is this an ideal of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Determine if this is an ideal of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$:

$$E=\{(2n, 3m): n,m \in \Bbb Z \}$$

So to show this is an ideal, I must show that it is closed under addition, closed with respect to negatives, and that it absorbs products.

---

So for addition: Take $(2n,3m),(2a,3b) \in E$ Then $(2n,3m)+(2a,3b) = (2(n+a),3(m+b))$.

And for negative: $-(2n,3m)=(-2n,3m)=(2(-n),3(-m))$. So that checks out as well.

---

Now I'm confused about how to show absorbs products. I'm pretty sure it does... $$\text{Take} \  (a,b) \in \Bbb Z. \ \text{Then} \  (2n,3m)(a,b)=(2(na),3(mb)) \in E$$

That one's easy. But showing that $(a,b)(2n,3m) \in E$ is less clear, since $E$ is not necessarily commutative:  $$(a,b)(2n,3m)=(a2n,b3m)=(2(na),3(mb)) \ ?$$

Comment: $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ is most definitely commutative.

Comment: So that means I can commute with the 2n and 3m?

Comment: You can write $a2n=2na$ and $b3m=3mb$ if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Remember that $a$, $n$, $b$, $m$, 2 and 3 are just plain old integers, not anything more exotic, and multiplication of integers is (of course) commutative.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z\times Z}$ is commutative - in fact, it's an Abelian group. Hence, $a2n=2na$ and $b3m=3mb$.